# Why does a constant force on a rigid body with a fixed axis of rotation produce more angular acceleration if applied farther from the axis?

Tags: classical-mechanics

I know the eq torque = Ia and also torque = Fr... it's easy to see mathematically but not physically. I want a simple physical justification for it.(may be microscopically).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because for a fixed angular displacement, the force is exerted through a larger distance the further it is applied from the axis, thus there is more work being done for that fixed angular displacement, and thus it experiences greater angular acceleration.

Comment: U mean more work means more KE at the end.. hmmmmm... an energy argument. But can you please give me a force argument?

Comment: @Neeladri Reddy: [Here's](https://www.quora.com/What-is-an-intuitive-explanation-for-why-torque-increases-with-radial-distance-in-a-lever) the best one I could find